# Почему не срабатывает submitHandler?

Tags: jquery, form, валидация, jquery-form, jquery-validation

Скажите пожалуйста, почему не появляется alert после заполнения формы и нажатия на кнопку.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".input-tel").inputmask("+7(999)999-99-99", {
    "clearIncomplete": true
  });
  jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
    debug: true,
    success: "valid"
  });

  $("#messageForm").validate({

    submitHandler: function(form) {
      alert('Форма отправлена!');
    },

    rules: {
      input_name: {
        required: true
      },
      input_tel: {
        required: true
      },
      input_email: {
        email: true
      },
      "contacts_check_accept[]": {
        required: true,
        minlength: 1
      },
    },
    messages: {
      input_name: {
        required: "Это поле обязательно к заполнению",
      },
      input_tel: {
        required: "Это поле обязательно к заполнению",
      },
      input_email: {
        email: "Введите пожалуйста корректный e-mail"
      },
      "contacts_check_accept[]": "Согласитесь с Политикой конфеденциальности"
    },
    focusCleanup: true,
    focusInvalid: false,
    errorClass: "form__input_error",
    validClass: "form__input_success"
  });

});
```

```html
<form id="messageForm" class="contacts__form form" action="#">

  <div class="form__group wow slideInUp">
    <div class="input-icon">
      <img class="lazyload" data-src="../../../../img/icons/input-user.svg" alt="">
    </div>
    <input class="form__control input" type="text" name="input_name" placeholder="Ваше имя*" required autocomplete="off">
  </div>

  <div class="form__group wow slideInUp">
    <div class="input-icon">
      <img class="lazyload" data-src="../../../../img/icons/input-tel.svg" alt="">
    </div>
    <input class="form__control input input-tel" type="text" name="input_tel" placeholder="Телефон*">
  </div>

  <div class="form__group wow slideInUp">
    <div class="input-icon">
      <img class="lazyload" data-src="../../../../img/icons/input-email.svg" alt="">
    </div>
    <input class="form__control input" type="email" name="input_email" placeholder="E-mail" autocomplete="off">
  </div>

  <div class="form__group wow slideInUp">
    <textarea class="form__control textarea" name="message" placeholder="Ваше сообщение"></textarea>
  </div>

  <div class="form__group wow slideInUp">
    <div class="form__info form__text">
      <span class="form__info_required">*</span> Поля, обязательные для заполнения
    </div>
    <div class="form__accept">
      <label class="check">
                <input class="check__input" name="contacts_check_accept[]" type="checkbox" checked required>
                <span class="check__box"></span>
            </label>
      <div class="form__text">
        Отправляя сообщение, я принимаю
        <a href="#" class="form__link">Пользовательское соглашение</a> и согласен с
        <a href="#" class="form__link">Политикой конфеденциальности</a> данного сайта.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form__btn wow slideInUp">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-yellow" id="form_btn">
            <img class="lazyload" data-src="../../../../img/icons/btn-icon-telegram-black.svg" alt="">
            Отправить заявку
        </button>
  </div>

</form>
```

Comment: Добавьте в форму method и action

Comment: @InDevX не помогло.

Comment: Посмотрите нет ли ошибок в консоли, если нет - попробуйте убрать с правил (и сообщений, соответственно) вот это `"contacts_check_accept[]"` и попробовать без него

Comment: код работает, проверь подключение библиотек или ошибки в консоле. https://jsfiddle.net/Diias/ta7skbch/2/

Comment: @Dias Вы правы, я отключил [этот](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/inputmask) плагин (для валидации номера телефона) и `alert` появляется.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Уточню свое сообщение в комментариях. Проблема не в плагине, а в коде.

```
$(".input-tel").inputmask("+7(999)999-99-99", {
  "clearIncomplete": true
});
jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
  debug: true,
  success: "valid"
});
```

Если поставить дефолтный код, то все работает.

```
$(".input-tel").inputmask("+7(999)999-99-99");
```